# Linux equivalent to Windows WriteProtect key in the registry for a software based write blocker?

Tags: linux, forensics

I unfortunately don't have access to a physical write blocker and am looking for a software based write blocker in Linux.

In Windows this can be achieved by modifying the registry and setting a DWORD named ***WriteProtect*** to 1 in ***HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies***.

Linux doesn't use registries but relies on files. Is there a file I can modify which will block writing to any removable drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ro (read-only) mount removable drives.

As to how you can set automount options is answered on [another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101634/how-to-set-default-auto-mount-options-for-removable-media).